# Is XFS a distributed file system or a journaling file system?

Tags: filesystem

Is XFS a distributed file system or a journaling file system?

In Wikipedia it says that XFS is a journaling file system, but in the [Berkely](http://now.cs.berkeley.edu/Xfs/xfs.html) website they mentioned that it is a serverless file system/Distributed file system.

Which one is true?

Comment: Upvote because I learnt something new today - never knew that the Berkely xFS even existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are true, because these are two different projects.

You should have noticed that:

- The latest xFS release was in [1997](http://now.cs.berkeley.edu/Xfs/release/).
- The Wikipedia article on XFS [doesn't link there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS#References), but to other sites. Such an article usually links to the project site, which seems to be [xfs.org](http://xfs.org/).

Please read more carefully.

Answer (score 6):

It appears you may be confusing XFS (a journaling file system) with xFS which appears to be something entirely different. Case matters.......